# htaccess redirect doesn't work for example.com to https://example.com

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, redirect

My goal with this redirection is the following:

- http:// --> https://
- www.example.com --> `example.com`
- example.com --> `https://example.com`

I am currently using the following for my .htaccess redirection:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

These rules work for all EXCEPT the following request:
example.com --> `example.com%7Brequest_uri%7D` NOT `https://example.com`

After doing some research, could the issue be with how the SSL is setup?  Or possibly some code within the host server configuration file?

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule to redirect from non-https to https:

```
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,QSA,R=permanent]
```